# How to deal with RoutingError while testing with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec

I created a controller called PolicyController and nested its route like this:

```
  scope "/your"
     resources :shops do
        resources :policies
     end
  end
```

Now when I'm trying to test this controller I keep getting this error:

```
  1) PoliciesController POST 'create' should be successful
     Failure/Error: post 'create'
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"policies", :action=>"create"}
     # ./spec/controllers/policies_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Not sure how to set it right. Would appreciate the help.

Edit: Forgot my specs:

```
describe PoliciesController do
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      post 'create'
      response.should be_success
    end
 end
```

Comment: Please post your specs, from the looks of it you are using a get on create action, it should be a post.

Comment: I changed the get to post, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you think this will work?

```
post :create, :shop_id => 1
```

Definitely want to create a new shop in a before block.